# What is the best IDE setup for web development?

Tags: django, development-environment

I am starting a little side project which consists of building a small-medium sized, django-based, website.

However, last time I was actually in the business of websites, was a few good years ago. So while still technologically capable, I'm still rusted on the tools/IDE part of websites.

I am looking for an IDE which can support the following:

- Basic HTML editing with syntax completion, highlighting, etc...
- Basic CSS editing with syntax completion, highlighting, etc...
- Python support for Django
- Support for the entire develop-debug-FTP upload cycle

If all of this could happen inside my existing eclipse installation, it would be nothing short of perfection.

So what's your recommendation on web development IDEs?

**EDIT:** forgot to add that I'm running Win XP on my dev machine.

---

**EDIT after answers:** thanks all you guys for the helpful advice. I think I'm going to go with **Aptana** as it fits in to eclipse which I already use. Also I will look into version control instead of simple FTP upload. Apparently I didn't know how much it is used even in web projects.

Comment: I would say it's Firefox with the Firebug add-on.

Comment: You should check jetbrains official student bundle offer. You can get online free student licence in 20 seconds for all these ides. [https://www.jetbrains.com/student](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/studio) with the Eclipse [PyDev plugin](http://www.aptana.com/python) to do all that (and a lot more).  The best thing is that it's cross-platform, so you can install it on any computer you do development work on, and not have to learn multiple IDEs.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure what platform you are on but Textmate can do all of that, as can Emacs.  I've heard e-Text-Editor is good on Windows (never used it though).

I would strongly suggest you replace your "develop-debug-FTP" cycle with a "write tests, develop, run tests, commit to version control" cycle.  You can then check out of version control onto the production server rather than ftp uploading.  I strongly recommend not using ftp with a web application (such as what you will create with Django).

You'll get more benefit from testing and version control than from using the best Ide in the world.

Comment: Just to add, TextMate will handle the commit to version control cycle as well.

Comment: Textmate is for Mac OSx the question environment is Windows XP!

Comment: I know, but I added the comment just before the OP edited the question to say so.

Comment: FWIW there is E which is a textmate clone for windows - but I haven't used it myself

Answer (score 4):

The [Zeus IDE](http://www.zeusedit.com) has **HTML** and **CSS** syntax highlighting and it can also be configured to do seamless **FTP**/**SFTP** editing.

Comment: +1 The seamless SFTP editing works well.

Answer (score 3):

We're using [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/Products/komodo_ide/komodo_edit.mhtml).

You can define a huge variety of sophisticated commands -- via scripting.

I haven't yet written an FTP transfer command, but I've done everything else by adding commands to my project in Komodo.

Comment: I've just started using Komodo Edit (love it so far), and would be interested to see a few examples of your scripts. This wouldn't be the right forum, perhaps a blog post?

Answer (score 3):

I use vim for python and django. It is free, solid as a rock, have many useful plugins and big community. For python/django coding you have auto-completion add syntax highlighting for django templates.

Comment: http://github.com/skyl/vim-config-python-ide

add a fork/branch :-)

or expose your own!

Answer (score 3):

Recently a new IDE for Django was released by JetBrains: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

- integrated version control system (supporting GIT)
- the best diff tool I've ever seen
- debugger

Answer (score 1):

[Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) is nice too for web development. For sure it handles Python, I don't know what could mean Python support for Django, but with coda you can work directly via FTP and do other nice stuff (also SVN versioning and has a good integrated CSS blender).

For Windows, when I developed web apps (in PHP) I found very useful PHPEd, but I don't think it can handle Python.

Answer (score 1):

For django, I use Eclipse+PyDev. It's by no means a complete code-completion solution, but it's a nice interface and it'll get you a long way.

Now for HTML, I use another editor. Eclipse does have an Aptana plugin (which is pretty okay) but I find it a bit clunky. Give it a look and see what you see. There are certainly enough HTML editors out there for you to find something that fits your flow. Just remember there's no reason why you have to do your python and html in the same editor. None at all.

In terms of pushing your code out, I plead you to see the error of your ways and move to some sort of version control system. I use [Bazaar](http://bazaar-vcs.org) but there are loads out there with various benefits. They take a while to get used to but they're well, well worth the initial time investment.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans won't do what you need yet (it will do some of it - i.e. it has some knowledge of HTML and css), but it may be worth keeping an eye on. There is some early version of python support available and I believe django support is expected to be added.

I can't vouch for the quality (as I use neither python nor django), however the ruby / ruby+rails support for netbeans works well and it supports other languages such as java and groovy well also.

In the meantime, textmate / E is probably your best bet. Many people use this rather than an IDE anyway.

Comment: NetBeans has an outstanding knowledge of HTML/CSS and JavaScript. (in terms of indentation, syntax highlighting and warnings/errors hinting)

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA has the best support for HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
It takes the web developer to the level of Java developers.

I am not affiliated to IntelliJ in anyway and unfortunately where I work right now we do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do worse than Dreamweaver for the HTML / CSS / visual side. Also try Netbeans for the programming parts - seems to support most languages.

Answer (score 0):

I have started a question very similar to this, hopefully the discussion benefits you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365676/which-ide-is-for-me

Cheers,